# Internal redirects issue in .htaccess Wordpress/WPMU

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I have a problem with a WPMU site running on my server.  Instead of a 404 message for a file I received a 500 server error.  I was able to troubeshoot this down to something in .htaccess. I'm receiving this apache error.

> [Fri Nov 18 10:00:54 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Request
>   exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I commented out the following and then received the 404 error instead of a 500 server error.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this or can anyone tell me why it's redirecting?  I'm not a .htaccess pro so anyone that can throw me a bone here would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is you need to remove those questionmarks as they will keep on matching, but i'm kind of guessing as you don't provide much info. What is it you want to achieve/what should the rules do? Which urls will result in a 500 error?

Comment: I didnt generate this code, I believe it's something WPMU has as part of its default installation.  I'm more worried about what it will break if I just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the rules generated by WP 3.8 network is faulty so changing it to the code below should work and stop the errors

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what fne stated to this issue. Thanks for that. But for my configuration:

wordpress subdomain multisite with domain mapping

The following rules worked fine:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # uploaded files
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
    RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```